# Make enter key click search button

Tags: php, html, jquery, enter

I am having trouble making enter key to hit the search button.... Please help me out. Thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
........
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../jQueryAssets/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">  


             function get() {
                  $.post ('data/data.php', { word: form.name.value },
                          function (output) {

                        $('#defination') .html(output).show() ;

                    });
             }       
    </script>        
.............

<form name ="form">
  <div align="center">
    <pre> <input name="name" type="text" autofocus required placeholder="Please enter a Word !"  size = "70" maxlength="50" >
    </pre>

    <p>
      <input type="button" onClick="get();" value="Search" size = "30" >
    .........
</html>
```

Comment: use onsubmit, not onclick. Also, make your submit button a submit button. Why is your function named "get" if it's posting?

Comment: and what does this have to do with PHP?

Answer (score 2):

you can use JQuery to submit form.

```
$(document).bind("keydown", function(event){
  if(event.which=="13")
   {
      $("#buttonID").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: @AshokHadiya accept answer please if it fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
$(document).bind("keydown", function(event){
 if(event.which=="13")
   {
    $("form").submit();
   }
});
```